# React native integrated app expo configuration error A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I'm trying to build a react native package to integrate with an andriod app, I'm using a template android app to test if there is a configuration that could potentially work. When I try to add expo to the above in order to be able to use expo libraries like expo-fonts I keep getting errors and the build keeps failling. Also without expo and axpo libraries the react native app is fully functional:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\ioann\Downloads\react-native-manual-setup-android-master\node_modules\expo-gl-cpp\android\build.gradle' line: 74

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-gl-cpp'.
> No signature of method: build_dc3qrybx70v962fdf5r1ztpro.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_dc3qrybx70v962fdf5r1ztpro$_run_closure3) values: [build_dc3qrybx70v962fdf5r
1ztpro$_run_closure3@2f6b06a1]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
/**************** Hermes Setup ********************/
project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: false
]
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);
/**************** End of Hermes Setup***************/
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.soumya.sethy.reactnativesetupandroid"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4'
    //PR Downloader
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0'
    implementation'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0+'

    //React Native Dependencies Setup Here...
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"

    //Hermes Dependencies Setup here...
    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
//(MainApplication) Manual ReactPackage Setup here...
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services';
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by building an expo app form scratch using expo init and then running expo eject once I was done.